# Shape Drawable View in XML

Tags: android, xml, view

I'm using the shapedrawable example word for word (nearly) and can't seem to call a shapedrawable class in xml. The only extra step stated by the documentation was to override the View(Context, AttributeSet), which I think I did. The docs I'm referring to are here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html Here is my code.

AndroidTest.java

```
package com.android.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AndroidTest extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```

ShapeSquare.java

```
package com.android.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.OvalShape;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class ShapeSquare extends View {
private ShapeDrawable mDrawable;

public ShapeSquare(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;
    int width = 300;
    int height = 50;

    mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
    mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
    mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    mDrawable.draw(canvas);
}
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<com.android.test.shapedrawable.ShapeSquare
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The error is a force quit error and I can't figure out where the problem lies. The shape properties will be dictated by user input (eventually), so the shape needs to be created in a class as opposed to all xml.

Comment: plz show your logcat output..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the problem here. I had to remove "shapedrawable" from:

```
<com.android.test.shapedrawable.ShapeSquare
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
/>
```

Apparently, that was just the location of the demo. I thought it was referencing the class somehow.